# First row in Recordset being deleted after a filter is specified

Tags: vbscript, ado

I know for a fact that the query I'm using to fill my Recordset below *does* return all 7 rows I'm looking for. However, the problem is that the first row (`PageId = 1`) gets omitted as soon as I specify a filter that should include that row anyway.

The ASP code below returns a table with all 7 rows.

```
<%
    response.write "<table>" & vbNewLine
    do while not Rs.eof
        response.write "<tr><td>" & Rs.Fields("question").Value & "</td></tr>" & vbNewLine
        Rs.MoveNext
    loop
    response.write "</table>" & vbNewLine
 %>
```

In the ASP code below, I've added a new line at the top that specifies a filter. It still loops 7 times, but the first row is now blank. The same thing happens if I try to do `Rs.MoveFirst` before the loop. It's as if the first row has somehow been deleted even though it should match the filter criteria.

```
<%
    Rs.Filter="PageId <= 7"
    response.write "<table>" & vbNewLine
    do while not Rs.eof
        response.write "<tr><td>" & Rs.Fields("question").Value & "</td></tr>" & vbNewLine
        Rs.MoveNext
    loop
    response.write "</table>" & vbNewLine
%>
```

Below is the code I'm usiong to open the Recordset:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
DIM Rs
SET Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "sp_getQuestions"
cmd.CommandType = 4
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Parameters("@qID") = 545
Set Rs = cmd.Execute
Set cmd=nothing
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1. What is `Rs.Fields("PageId").Type`? 2. You say "the first row is now blank"...does that mean the "<tr><td>" tags are there, but no contents, or that the entire row is not printed out?

Answer (score 0):

For a common recordset, you can use **Rs.RecordCount** both before and after to ensure you have same number of results. You can also use **Rs.AbsolutePosition** (1-based) to ensure you're still on the first record. When I have doubts or issues with where the RS begins, I use **Rs.MoveFirst** to make sure it's at the beginning.

For a Stored Procedure, you might consider using [.GetRows](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_getrows.asp) and then UBound (+1) for the count... looping through the result array to display:

```
If NOT rs.EOF Then
    arrResultSet = rs.GetRows()
    arrRowCount = UBound(arrResultSet,2)
End If
```

I've not used this method, but it looks like you may be able to guarantee more realistic results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rs.RecordCount always returns -1, both before and after setting the filter. There is data in there, so I have no idea why it's returning -1. `AbsolutePosition` and `MoveFirst` also don't do anything in this case.

Comment: Please provide the code you use to open the Recordset. It is not normal behavior for a RS to return -1 when there is a valid RS with records returned.

Comment: Ok, added to the main post just now.

Comment: What's the cursor location? Client-side
cursor may improve odds of having those work, but also cause extra burden on webserver (vs SQL Server): rs.CursorLocation=adUseClient

Comment: It's not letting me change that for some reason. Even after attempting to change it to adUseClient, it'll return "2" (adUseServer) when I check its value.